# Transmission-daemon permission denied in /home/pi/ folder. How to fix it?

Tags: permissions, bittorrent, raspbian, transmission

I don't want to use any USB drive with my Raspberry Pi because my SD card has 32GB storage. So i put `/home/pi/torrent/downloads` and `/home/pi/torrent/incompleted` location in the `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` file. But I'm getting error everytime after downloading 4mb of any torrent. I have also tried changing `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` replaced the line `"USER=debian-transmission"` with `"USER=pi"`, changed the ownership of /`home/pi/torrent/downloads` and  `/home/pi/torrent/incompleted` to pi:pi but still not working.

Here is my full `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` code:

```
    {
        "alt-speed-down": 50,                                              "alt-speed-enabled": false,
        "alt-speed-time-begin": 540,
        "alt-speed-time-day": 127,                                         "alt-speed-time-enabled": false,
        "alt-speed-time-end": 1020,                                        "alt-speed-up": 50,
        "bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0",                                    "bind-address-ipv6": "::",
        "blocklist-enabled": false,
        "blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist",
        "cache-size-mb": 4,
        "dht-enabled": true,
        "download-dir": "/home/pi/torrent/downloads",                      "download-limit": 100,
        "download-limit-enabled": 0,                                       "download-queue-enabled": true,
        "download-queue-size": 5,
        "encryption": 1,
        "idle-seeding-limit": 30,
        "idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false,
        "incomplete-dir": "/home/pi/torrent/incompleted",
        "incomplete-dir-enabled": true,
        "lpd-enabled": false,
        "max-peers-global": 200,
        "message-level": 1,
        "peer-congestion-algorithm": "",
        "peer-id-ttl-hours": 6,
        "peer-limit-global": 200,
        "peer-limit-per-torrent": 50,
        "peer-port": 51413,
        "peer-port-random-high": 65535,
        "peer-port-random-low": 49152,
        "peer-port-random-on-start": false,
        "peer-socket-tos": "default",
        "pex-enabled": true,                                               "port-forwarding-enabled": false,
        "preallocation": 1,                                                "prefetch-enabled": true,
        "queue-stalled-enabled": true,
        "queue-stalled-minutes": 30,                                       "ratio-limit": 2,
        "ratio-limit-enabled": false,
        "rename-partial-files": true,
        "rpc-authentication-required": true,
        "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
        "rpc-enabled": true,
        "rpc-host-whitelist": "",
        "rpc-host-whitelist-enabled": true,
        "rpc-password": "{password$
        "rpc-port": 9091,
        "rpc-url": "/transmission/",
        "rpc-username": "pi",
    "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1",
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": false,
    "scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true,
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": false,
    "script-torrent-done-filename": "",
    "seed-queue-enabled": false,
    "seed-queue-size": 10,                                             "speed-limit-down": 100,
    "speed-limit-down-enabled": false,                                 "speed-limit-up": 100,
    "speed-limit-up-enabled": false,
    "start-added-torrents": true,                                      "trash-original-torrent-files": false,                             "umask": 18,
    "upload-limit": 100,
    "upload-limit-enabled": 0,
    "upload-slots-per-torrent": 14,
    "utp-enabled": true
}
```